# How to completely disable tracking/collection in AdMob?

Tags: swift, admob, app-store, gdprconsentform

I want to show ads in my iOS app, but I don't want to track/collect any user behaviour/data so I don't have to deal with GDPR consent or privacy policy stuff.

My code so far:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().disableSDKCrashReporting()
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.setSameAppKeyEnabled(false)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "gad_has_consent_for_cookies")
        return true
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd like to know the same...

Comment: I’d also like to know.  I prefer providing a safe environment for users.

Comment: I'd also like to know the same.